# Linq where clause confusion

Tags: c#, linq

Good day, everyone!

I've written one query for my Automation test, but it's taking too long to execute, and I'm not sure how to optimize it effectively because I'm new to the Linq where clause.

Could someone please assist me with this?

```
var order = OrderRepositoryX.GetOrderByStatus(OrderStatusType.Dispatched, 4000)
            .Where(x => x.siteId == 1 || x.siteId == 10 || x.siteId == 8 || x.siteId == 16 || x.siteId == 26 || x.siteId == 27)
            .Where(x =>
            {
                var totalPrice = OrderRepository.GetOrderById(shared_parameters.testConfiguration, x.orderId).TotalPrice;
                if (totalPrice < 500)
                    return false;
                return true;
            })
            .Where(x =>
            {
                var cnt = ReturnOrderRepositoryX.CheckReturnOrderExists(x.orderId);
                if (cnt > 0)
                    return false;
                return true;
            })
            .Where(x =>
            {
                var cnt = OrderRepositoryX.CheckActiveOrderJobDetailsByOrderId(x.orderId);
                if (cnt > 0)
                    return false;
                return true;
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: try to execute each `where` as a own statement in debug mode to find out which clause is  slowing down your application

Comment: It is EF or just LINQ to Entities?

Comment: You have other repository code being executed in where clause... That means your linq query is not translated to SQL. It might be pulling all the data in memory and then applies condition on it. That's one of the reasons you have slow performance.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - it is EF

Comment: @draz - Okay - I'll check in debug this

Comment: Well, you are trying to work with database as with collection of objects - bad idea. Too many unknown parts, repositories, its methods. Uncover them and probably it is possible to create optimal LINQ query.

Comment: You're only showing black-box code here. Impossible for us to see what's going on. We don't even know what you're using to access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this instead
Avoid too many where clauses. It gets a result and then applies another check on the whole set.

```
var order = OrderRepositoryX.GetOrderByStatus(OrderStatusType.Dispatched, 4000)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.siteId == 1 || x.siteId == 10 || x.siteId == 8 || x.siteId == 16 ||
                                x.siteId == 26 || x.siteId == 27) &&
                (x =>
                {
                    var totalPrice = OrderRepository.GetOrderById(shared_parameters.testConfiguration, x.orderId)
                        .TotalPrice;
                    return totalPrice >= 500;
                })
                && (x =>
                {
                    var cnt = ReturnOrderRepositoryX.CheckReturnOrderExists(x.orderId);
                    return cnt <= 0;
                })
                && (x =>
                {
                    var cnt = OrderRepositoryX.CheckActiveOrderJobDetailsByOrderId(x.orderId);
                    return cnt <= 0;
                });
```

Comment: Thank you Smitha - I will try this approach

Answer (score 2):

The biggest code smell here is that you are calling other repositories inside the `Where` clause which (assuming that repositories actually hit database) it will effectively mean that you are hitting database per every queried item. Lets  imagine that `OrderRepositoryX.GetOrderByStatus(OrderStatusType.Dispatched, 4000)` and first `Where` will result in 1000 items, only second `Where`clause will lead to 1000 queries to the database (and you have some more calls to repositories in subsequent `Where`s). And all of this to get just one item (i.e. `FirstOrDefault`).

Usual approach is to avoid calling database in loops (what `Where` basically does here) and rewrite such code so only single SQL query will be performed against the database returning only what is needed and performing all the filtering on the database side.